# Getting incomplete json as result of toD(url) for few cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am using apache camel and fetching data from data lake which is owned by another system.
While in most of the cases this flow works absolutely fine but for very few events i have observed that incomplete data is received by my application
and flow breaks saying
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value

I have check with the team who source the data - but they had already confirmed that no changes has happened at there end, which left me clueless how can i troubleshoot this issue further

if i use curl command and download the data from data lake i get the complete json
is there any other way in apache camel which i can try to download the data from the dataSetAccessUrl ?
quick help will be appreciated as this is a prod issue

using :
camel-spring-boot-bom > 3.9.0
camel-spring-boot-dependencies > 3.9.0

```
    from("direct:fetchData")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "Invoking API ")
    .toD("${header.dataSetAccessUrl}") // accessing CCO  data sets
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "response code is: ${header.CamelHttpResponseCode}, JSON Response ${body}")
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, LOGGER, "JSON Response ${body}").end();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)):` means that the JSON-response has illegal character. When this happens you should write the failed JSON response to a file and view it in VSCode or some other editor that supports syntax-highlighting for JSON.

```java
from("direct:fetchData")
    .onException(JsonMappingException.class)
        .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "Json mapping failed. ${exception.message}")
        .to("file:{{fetchdata.mapping.failed}}")
    .end()
    // ...
;
```

Once had this happen with client when users had copy pasted data directly from pdf files which had control characters like STX (Start of text).

This is best fixed in the source to avoid having to clean this in every application using the REST-API, but you can also remove specific control characters from message body using replaceAll and regex.

```java
// Removes stx control character from message body
String body = exchange.getMessage().getBody(String.class);
exchange.getMessage().setBody(body.replaceAll("[\\x02]", ""));
```

The `.toD("header.dataSetAccessUrl")` has nothing to do with this but you might want to validate that header at the start of the route. Like throwing exception when the header is null.

Comment: Thanks Pasi, but removal of control characters will come in case if i receive complete json with those control characters. In my case i am not receiving the complete json it self. :( 

Header validations are in place - like if its null route itself will not get called.

Comment: If you're not getting the complete JSON the issue is in your request or in the API. Camels http returns the response body as is unless the server returns response code of 400 or above in which chase it will throw an exception by default.

Comment: Well as i mentioned earlier is working fine for most of the requests only for few requests incomplete JSON is returned with response code 200
Thats the problem i am not getting root cause for this issue

Comment: Then you better log out the `dataSetAccessUrl` header when that happens and test the request using curl or something like [postman](https://www.postman.com/).  If the json-response is missing some fields or includes some fields lacking from your model class you might need to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation on top of your model classes.

Comment: I tried using the curl command - with curl command i am getting complete json

so i think this could be some framework issue or not sure why i am not receiving complete data.

Comment: dataSetAccessUrl  has the complete data lake path along with json file name

Comment: Pasi Österman
- I tried with below in application.properties file - still getting the same
`spring.jackson.parser.allow-unquoted-control-chars=true` Not sure what else can i add in route or properties file to download complete json data or is there any other approach to try for triggering the URL and downloading the json

Comment: Apache Camels http-component doesn't care about control characters in the response body only the jackson parser does. If the message body **before unmarshal** doesn't contain the complete json-response then the problem is very likely in your request or API. Try storing the body as string to exchange property before marshal and log it during exception to see if its complete. Its possible that failed marshal mutates the body especially if it's type of stream resulting in incomplete json-response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251027/discussion-between-trups-and-pasi-osterman).